# How to implement Serializable for my project to have persistence?

Tags: java, serialization, javafx, serializable, observablelist

My main method:

```
public class ToDoList extends Application{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    Pane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ToDoList.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("ToDoListStyle.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Plan yourself");
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

}

Then a part of controller:

```
    ObservableList<EventsBean> dataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    System.out.println("The pane loaded");

    List<String> myList;
    try {
        myList = Files.lines(Paths.get("src/com/todolist/EventsList.txt")).collect(Collectors.toList());
        eventsSelector.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(myList));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Don t find file");
    }

    removeCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(removeCol));
    eventCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<EventsBean, String>("event"));
    dateCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<EventsBean, LocalDate>("date"));
    doneCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<EventsBean, String>("done"));
    doneCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<EventsBean>forTableColumn());
    doneCol.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<EventsBean, String> t) -> {
        ((EventsBean) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()))
                .setDone(t.getNewValue());
    });
    observationCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<EventsBean, String>("observation"));
    removeCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().selectedProperty());
    observationCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<EventsBean>forTableColumn());
    observationCol.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<EventsBean, String> t) -> {
        ((EventsBean) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()))
                .setObservation(t.getNewValue());
    });
    observationCol.setSortable(false);

    eventsTable.setItems(dataList);
    eventsTable.setEditable(true);

    bttnAddEvent.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
        try {
            text = eventsSelector.getValue().toString();
            dataList.add(new EventsBean(text, isoDate, "",  "", false));
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            System.out.println("Nothing selected");
        }
    });

    bttnRemove.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
        ObservableList<EventsBean> dataListToRemove = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (EventsBean bean : dataList) {
            if (bean.getSelected()) {
                dataListToRemove.add(bean);
            }
        }
        dataList.removeAll(dataListToRemove);

        // Below code it is for delete a focused row
        // EventsBean selectedItem = eventsTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        // eventsTable.getItems().remove(selectedItem);
    });

}
```

Then the EventsBean:

```
public class EventsBean {


private SimpleStringProperty event;
private SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate> date;
private SimpleStringProperty done;
private SimpleStringProperty observation;
private SimpleBooleanProperty selected;

public EventsBean(String event, LocalDate date, String done, String observation, boolean selected) {
    this.event = new SimpleStringProperty(event);
    this.date = new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>(date);
    this.done = new SimpleStringProperty(done);
    this.observation = new SimpleStringProperty(observation);
    this.selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty(selected);
}
// Getters and Setters ...
```

I want to serialize the data in the table. The serializable object I think is dataList from ObservableList. My problem is where to implement the Serializable interface? This are the best solution in my case for persistence?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The classes that you serialize are the ones that have to be serializable. In this case, `ObservableList` and `EventsBean`. This is rather basic.

Comment: @EJP But note that the JavaFX property classes (`SimpleStringProperty`, etc) do not implement `Serializable`, which makes it a little trickier.

Comment: @James_D Agreed, but I don't know why you're addressing that to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first ask yourself if you really want to use object serialization here. It might be better to use a different persistence approach: e.g. use a JSON marshaling library such as [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson). Most such libraries just use an object's `get` and `set` methods to find the data, so would likely work with your `EventsBean` class with little additional code.

If you do want to use Java object serialization, you need to make the `EventsBean` class `Serializable`. Normally this is straightforward, but the problem you will run into is that the JavaFX Properties classes do not implement `Serializable`, so naïvely making `EventsBean` implement `Serializable` and attempting to serialize instances of it will generate runtime exceptions. You need to use custom serialization to do this.

First, make the JavaFX properties `transient`, so the default serialization mechanism does not attempt to serialize them, and then define custom `readObject` and `writeObject` methods to define how the objects should be serialized:

```
public class EventsBean implements Serializable {


    private transient SimpleStringProperty event;
    private transient SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate> date;
    private transient SimpleStringProperty done;
    private transient SimpleStringProperty observation;
    private transient SimpleBooleanProperty selected;

    // constructors...

    // example get/set/property methods:
    public StringProperty eventProperty() {
        return event ;
    }

    public final String getEvent() {
        return eventProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setEvent(String event) {
        eventProperty().set(event);
    }

    // etc. for other properties...


    // custom serialization:
    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream s) throws IOException {
        s.defaultWriteObject();
        s.writeObject(getEvent()); // write event as a plain String
        s.writeObject(getDate()); 
        s.writeObject(getDone());
        s.writeObject(getObservation());
        s.writeBoolean(isSelected());
    }

    // custom deserialization:
    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream s) throws IOException {
        s.defaultReadObject();
        this.event = new SimpleStringProperty((String)s.readObject());
        this.data = new SimpleObjectProperty<>((LocalDate)s.readObject());
        this.done = new SimpleStringProperty((String)s.readObject());
        this.observation = new SimpleStringProperty((String)s.readObject());
        this.selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty(s.readBoolean());
    }
}
```

Finally, you also need to note that `ObservableList` implementations are typically not serializable, so you need to serialize a "regular" list in order to serialize the data, i.e.:

```
ObjectOutputStream s = ... ;
s.writeObject(new ArrayList<EventsBean>(dataList));
```

and to read it back:

```
ObjectInputStream s = ... ;
dataList.setAll((List<EventsBean>)s.readObject());
```

Comment: Ok, I tried the above solution, but I have problems with deserialization. Then I thought of using the GSON library, but also it is serializing, and at deserialization I have errors: